# how to get the value of @DiscriminatorColumn()?

Tags: java, jpa

hello
I have a problem with inheritance in EJB. I show you my code after

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PROJ_TYPE")
@Table(name="PROJECT")
public abstract class Project {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("L");
@Table(name="LARGEPROJECT")
public class LargeProject extends Project {
  private BigDecimal budget;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S");
@Table(name="SMALLPROJECT")
public class SmallProject extends Project {
}
```

how to get the value of

> PROJ_TYPE

. the only solution that I use nativeQuery ,but is there another solution???

sorry for my english and 
thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need this? What's the goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the DiscriminatorValue at run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005383/how-to-get-the-discriminatorvalue-at-run-time)

Answer (score 4):

It should also be possible to map the discriminator as an additional column, as long as it is not updatable or insertable.

```
@Column(name="PROJ_TYPE", nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable=false)
private String projectType;
```

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this 
 my problem was how to get value of PROJ_TYPE from datbase because i don’t have a get for PROJ_TYPE in entity