# Performance of calling Method/Field.getAnnotation(Class) several times vs. Pre-caching this data in a Map

Tags: java, performance, reflection, dictionary, annotations

I'd like to know if there are any comparison/studies about the performance of repeatidly calling (in Java) the `Method.getAnnotation(Class)` and `Field.getAnnotation(Class)` methods, versus storing (at program start up time) a precomputed Map with this metadata information of the classes and querying it repeatidly later. Which one would provide the best runtime performance?

And this performance would be the same under Java 5, 6 and 7?

Answer (score 13):

Map should be a more preferable approach. The main issue is not only about caching. But also improve the multi thread contention. In the Method.getAnnotation(), it calls a synchronized private method declaredAnnotations(). Synchronized method have bad impact on highly threaded application.

Comment: On a multi-threaded Java EE application, where `getAnnotation` was being called 18k times, the measured wall time went down from 3.7s to 0.09s by using a `ConcurrentHasMap` for caching.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is some rather old question but the result for more recent JDKs might still be of interest.

I wrote some JMH benchmark to get an idea of the impact caching of annotation information might have:

```java
@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class StateWithMethodAndHashMap {
    public StateWithMethodAndHashMap() {
        try {
            cache = new HashMap<>();
            method = AnnotationCachingBenchmark.class.getMethod("methodWithAnnotations");
            final Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class);
            cache.put(method, annotation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    final HashMap<Method, Annotation> cache;
    final Method method;
}

@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class StateWithMethodAndConcurrentHashMap {
    public StateWithMethodAndConcurrentHashMap() {
        try {
            cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            method = AnnotationCachingBenchmark.class.getMethod("methodWithAnnotations");
            cache.put(method, method.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    final ConcurrentHashMap<Method, Annotation> cache;
    final Method method;
}

@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class StateWithMethod {
    public StateWithMethod() {
        try {
            method = AnnotationCachingBenchmark.class.getMethod("methodWithAnnotations");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    final Method method;
}

@Deprecated
public void methodWithAnnotations() {
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.All)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public void annotationsByReflection(final Blackhole aBh, final StateWithMethod aState) throws Exception {
    aBh.consume(aState.method.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class)
            || aState.method.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class));
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.All)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public void annotationsByHashMap(final Blackhole aBh, final StateWithMethodAndHashMap aState) throws Exception {
    aBh.consume(aState.cache.get(aState.method));
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.All)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public void annotationsByConcurrentHashMap(final Blackhole aBh, final StateWithMethodAndConcurrentHashMap aState)
        throws Exception {
    aBh.consume(aState.cache.get(aState.method));
}
```

JDK 1.8.0_172, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 25.172-b11:

```
Benchmark                                                   Mode    Cnt      Score      Error   Units
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByConcurrentHashMap  thrpt      5      0.152 ±    0.009  ops/ns
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByHashMap            thrpt      5      0.144 ±    0.005  ops/ns
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByReflection         thrpt      5      0.043 ±    0.001  ops/ns

AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByConcurrentHashMap   avgt      5      6.610 ±    0.094   ns/op
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByHashMap             avgt      5      6.963 ±    0.414   ns/op
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByReflection          avgt      5     23.248 ±    0.339   ns/op
```

JDK 13, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 13+33:

```
Benchmark                                                   Mode    Cnt       Score      Error   Units
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByConcurrentHashMap  thrpt      5       0.128 ±    0.027  ops/ns
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByHashMap            thrpt      5       0.136 ±    0.031  ops/ns
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByReflection         thrpt      5       0.139 ±    0.010  ops/ns

AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByConcurrentHashMap   avgt      5       7.335 ±    1.067   ns/op
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByHashMap             avgt      5       6.634 ±    0.184   ns/op
AnnotationCachingBenchmark.annotationsByReflection          avgt      5       7.234 ±    0.567   ns/op
```

You can clearly see the effect of annotations being cached by the JDK comparing 1.8 to 13. So with recent JDKs there is no need to care about caching this information as it would only introduce additional overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the update and benchmarks! It looks like the syncrhonized blocks in the reflection code was changed to lock-free CAS operations, which helps and makes the older answers here a little less relevant for newer JVMs.

Comment: I wonder if that's still the case in the latest AdoptOpenJDK/Temurin/RedHat builds of Java 8. Gotta test that later.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this depends a bit on the JVM implementation. But taking the example of Oracle JVM, it maintains a cache of all the annotations on the method and field instances which is equivalent to the map approach you speak of.

But there is a catch here; since method/field instances are unique to each object, in case you end up creating a lot of objects for a given class, you pretty much lose out on the performance benefit offered. It is in this case a static map of class-name + method-name / class-name + field name to the relevant annotation list trumps the in-built caching approach used.

BTW, how are you pre-computing the map? Is it done on application start-up or some auto-generated code? Have you really confirmed that it is safe to cache the annotation instances in your case?

As always, for such questions, the best solution is to profile/measure with your app on the line and go with the solution which looks like win in the given use case.

Comment: A little bit of context: this will be part of a MVC web framework, specifically, the annotations will be attached to the Action classes, their methods and fields, so it is expected to generate lots of new instances over the life time of the application. I actually did it using the direct getAnnotation() approach but I guess I could pre-compute the map at context initialization. no autogenerated code is in the framework by now.

Comment: Pre-computing at the context initialization time sounds like a decent choice given that the classes would be loaded once and never changed again.