# Is this the right way to cache reflection data?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm working on some webservices, which I'm implementing with hibernate. The issue is that I need to access the names of the entity tables (say, those in @Table("Table_A")).
The code is generated, so I cannot alter the entity classes themselves to give me what I need.

This is what I was doing so far:

```
public static
<T extends Entity<K>, K extends Serializable>
String getTableName(Class<T> objClass) {
    Table table = objClass.getAnnotation(Table.class);
    return (table != null)? table.name() : null;
}
```

However, after some research I discovered that reflection is not the best performance-wise, and since this method will be called a lot I'm looking for another way to go at it.

I'm trying to follow the advice given here:
[Performance of calling Method/Field.getAnnotation(Class) several times vs. Pre-caching this data in a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098648/performance-of-calling-method-field-getannotationclass-several-times-vs-pre-c).

This is what I came up with:

```
public final class EntityUtils {
    private static HashMap<String, String> entityCache;

    private EntityUtils() {
        entityCache = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public static
    <T extends Entity<K>, K extends Serializable>
    String getTableName_New(Class<T> objClass) {
        String tableName = entityCache.get(objClass.getCanonicalName());

        if (tableName == null) {
            Table table = objClass.getAnnotation(Table.class);

            if (table != null) {
                tableName = table.name();
                entityCache.put(objClass.getCanonicalName(), tableName);
            }
        }

        return tableName;
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure about this. Is it a good idea to cache reflection data in a static map? Is there any alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: Note the `key.getSimpleName()` in Sean's answer which ist the default table name if no `@Table` annotation is specified. Adding this will also have the benefit of making sure of having an etry in your map for each class that has been requested. In your actual code a missing `@Table` annotation will always perform a reflection lookup to only find `null`.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, I would use a [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) cache, with weak keys, that way you're not keeping any references to the class object in case you use some advanced ClassLoader magic.

```
LoadingCache<Class<?>, String> tableNames = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .weakKeys()
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Class<?>, String>() {
             public String load(Class<?> key) {
                 Table table = objClass.getAnnotation(Table.class);
                 return table == null ? key.getSimpleName() : table.name();
             }
           });
```

Usage:

```
String tablename = tableNames.get(yourClass);
```

See: [Caches Explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

---

On the other hand: annotations are cached by the JDK also, so your previous approach is probably fine