# How to use discriminator value in Ebean queries when using single table inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, ebean, single-table-inheritance

I have the following entities with single table inheritance strategy.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class Vehicle extends com.avaje.ebean.Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("b")
public class Bus extends Vehicle {
    public String field1;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("c")
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public String field2;
}
```

I have a table in my UI that should show rows with columns of Vehicle's fields. I want to put an advanced search that user can filter Vehicles list by their types.

**My question is how can I create a query to filter list by Vehicle's type.** Something like this:

```
List<Vehicle> list = com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.find(Vehicle.class)
    .where().eq("type", "c").findList();
```

If I insert a field with below definition that have been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005383/how-to-get-the-discriminatorvalue-at-run-time), I would get an error with message "Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property theType not found in [id, name, description] for type class models.Vehicle"

```
@Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public String theType;
```

If I set it to @Transient, I could not use it in queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @Formula annotation, as it has been explained in [ebean docs](https://archive-avaje-org.github.io/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/Formula.html).

```
@Transient
@Formula(select = "type")
public String theType;
```

Of course notice that:

> As the field is also Transient it is not included by default in queries - it needs to be explicitly included.